# why is my char array empty

Tags: esp8266, c++, eeprom

following sketch will run totally fine and as expected :

```
#include <Wire.h>

#include "SparkFun_External_EEPROM.h"
ExternalEEPROM ExtEEPROM;
char username[33] = "";
char password[65] = "";

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);
  Wire.begin();
  #define EEPROM_ADDRESS 0b1011000 // 0x58
  ExtEEPROM.setMemorySize(256000/8); // 256kbit = 32kbyte
  ExtEEPROM.setPageSize(64); // 64 byte page size.
  ExtEEPROM.enablePollForWriteComplete();
  ExtEEPROM.setPageWriteTime(10); // max. ms for AT24C128
  if (ExtEEPROM.begin(EEPROM_ADDRESS, Wire) == false) 
  {
    Serial.println("No memory detected. Freezing.");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("Memory detected!");

  String uuu = "myusername";
  String ppp = "mypassword";

  uuu.toCharArray(username, sizeof(username) - 1);
  ppp.toCharArray(password, sizeof(password) - 1);
  Serial.print("password=");Serial.println(password);
  ExtEEPROM.put(0, username);
  //delay(100);
  ExtEEPROM.put(0 + sizeof(username), "greatnewpassword");
}
  
void loop() {
  char xxx[33] = "";
  ExtEEPROM.get(0, xxx);
  Serial.print("xxx=");Serial.println(xxx); // prints the username

  char yyy[33] = "";
  ExtEEPROM.get(0 + sizeof(username), yyy);
  Serial.print("yyy=");Serial.println(yyy); // prints the password
  delay(1000);
}
```

However, if I replace `ExtEEPROM.put(0 + sizeof(username), "greatnewpassword");` to `ExtEEPROM.put(0 + sizeof(username), password);`, then `yyy` prints empty in the serial monitor. Why?

Comment: Try doing a serial print of password to see if the toCharArray call did what it was supposed to do.

Comment: OT: Don't write `any_boolean == false`, use `!any_boolean`. If you think think, you should make sure that anyone understands, then I'd recommend `(any_boolean == false) == true`. :-D

Comment: OT: `sizeof` is an operator, not a function, so use `sizeof variable`. However, its operand can be a type, and then it needs parentheses for syntactIcal reasons. This leads to this ubiquitous bad habit to write it as a function.

Comment: Are you sure you are putting the actual _array_ `password`, rather than a pointer produced by its decay (like `char *foo = password; ExtEEPROM.put(..., foo);`)?

Comment: 256kbit is not 256000 bits. It's 256 * 1024 bits, or 262144.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem seems to be the lib I am using. I think it can not handle data overlapping page size.

if I replace from this

```
char username[33] = "";
char password[65] = "";
```

to this:

```
char username[16] = "";
char password[16] = "";
```

everything works fine as it saves and reads from the EEPROM via I2C.

Comment: the conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134577/discussion-on-answer-by-musa-why-is-my-char-array-empty).

Answer (score 2):

As Majenko already mentions:

> .get() and .put() should only be used for atomic, self-contained,
> types like int or float, not pointers like char *.

Not sure what atomic means here, but you may .put and .get any data type, especially a struct.

```
struct EPROMData {
  char username[33];
  char password[65];
}; 
EPROMData data {"myusername","mypassword"};

void setup() {
   ...
   ExtEEPROM.put(0,data);
}
void loop() {
   EPROMData d;
   ExtEEPROM.get(0,d);
   Serial.print("user="); Serial.println(d.username); 
   ...
}
```

Sure, if the data type is a pointer or a String object (containing a pointer only), you won't be happy with .put / .get

Comment: By atomic I mean "it is a thing complete in itself". A struct is complete. An int is complete. A char * is not complete since it doesn't contain the data, it is only a pointer to it. So it's not "atomic". Same goes for a String object, since the object doesn't contain the string data, only a pointer to allocated memory that contains the string data.

Answer (score 1):

`.get` and `.put` are being passed a char pointer, not the contents of a char array. Thus you're not writing the content of the string but the address in memory where it's being stored.

With a string literal that is fixed and never changes, so what you write and what you read are fine. With a variable though the address could be anything, and storing the address of some RAM where a string is stored is pointless.

`.get()` and `.put()` should only be used for atomic, self-contained, types like `int` or `float`, not pointers like `char *`.

Instead you need to be using the `.read(address, buffer, size)` and `.write(address, buffer, size)` functions to read and write the contents of your char arrays.

Comment: In the OP's code, `get()` and `put()` are being passed actual arrays, not pointers. As the arrays are being passed _by reference_, they do _not_ decay to pointers.